# How can I configure my miner for two pools simultaneously?

Tags: mining-pools, cgminer, miner-configuration

I have a single sc 30gh/s miner.
I want to run `cgminer` as well `guminer` at a time simultaneously, will there be any difference?

I want to use `cgminer` to mine at BTCGUILD and `guminer` for mining at SLUSHPOOL.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I downvoted, because your question is nearly illegible and it is hard to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the cgminer -c (config option) to add multiple pools and set up quota system to mine a certain percentage on each pool.

From the CGMiner Readme:

```
"pools" : [
        {
                "url" : "poola:porta",
                "user" : "usernamea",
                "pass" : "passa"
        },
        {
                "quota" : "2;poolb:portb",
                "user" : "usernameb",
                "pass" : "passb"
        }
]
```

Will assign 2/3 to poolb, and 1/3 to poola.